# How to bring GUI window to front after an event?

Tags: powershell

As the title says, how can I bring a Powershell GUI window in front of another window after an event has happened, if it is at all possible? As in, I have, for example, Firefox opened and the Powershell GUI is running behind it, after certain event happens inside of the Powershell it pops in front of the Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you can use [`[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.appactivate) to reactivate your own process' main window via the process ID, as reflected in the [automatic `$PID` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pid):

```bash
# Enable cross-process window activation (see below).
(Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -PassThru -Namespace "Random.Ns$PID.AllowWindowActivation" -Name WinApiHelper -MemberDefinition @'
  [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SystemParametersInfo")]
  static extern bool SystemParametersInfo_Set_UInt32(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, UInt32 pvParam, uint fWinIni);
  public static void AllowWindowActivation()
  {
    if (! SystemParametersInfo_Set_UInt32(0x2001 /* SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT */, 0, 0 /* timeout in secs */, 0 /* non-persistent change */)) {
      throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Unexpected failure calling SystemParametersInfo() with SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT");
    }
  }
'@)::AllowWindowActivation()

# Load the required assembly.
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic

# Launch a sample GUI application that will steal the focus
# (will become the foreground application).
Start-Process notepad.exe

# Wait a little.
Start-Sleep 3 

# Now reactivate the main window of the current process.
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($PID)
```

Note:

- ***General* programmatic activation of arbitrary windows *across process boundaries* is *prevented* by default**:

  - Instead of the targeted window getting *activated*, its ***taskbar button* flashes**, so as to signal to the user the *intent* to make the window active.
  - However, **programmatic activation from code running *in the current foreground window* seems to always be permitted**.
- The [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) `-MemberDefinition` call above *overrides* this for the current session using a P/Invoke call to the [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow) WinAPI function, via setting its `SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT` parameter to `0`.

  - This will incur a one-time compilation performance penalty per session.
  - Cross-process window activation will be enabled for the remainder of the session, for *all* processes.
  - **[Doesn't work anymore in W10+]** The alternative is to *persistently* configure your user account to allow activation, via the registry:

    - Set the [`ForegroundLockTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc957208(v=technet.10)) per-user registry value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` to `0` (the default is `200000` msecs., i.e. 3 minutes and 20 secs); requires *logging off* or rebooting for the change to take effect:

      ```bash
      Set-ItemProperty 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop' ForegroundLockTimeout 0
      ```

Comment: Good alternative to native `SetForegroundWindow()`, so P/Invoke can be avoided. Under the hood it propably calls `SetForegroundWindow` after determining the "main window" of the process, so it actually just flashes the taskbar button instead of actively setting the window to the foreground.

Comment: Thanks man, I found exactly that code prior to posting this question, but couldn't find the way to determine the PID of my program/script. So this does it, thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, @zett42. On my machine I never see the flashing behavior and I don't know why: the `ForegroundLockTimeout` registry value is at its default, but the `SystemParametersInfo()` WinAPI function indeed indicates that activation is _allowed_, but I don't know where that is set (it is _not_ related to Developer Mode, which is off on my machine). Do you have an explanation?

Comment: @zett42, as for `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate()`, specifically: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19789921/45375) claims that the method uses a hack to unconditionally support activation. If you have a machine where `SetForegroundWindow` fails to activate, can you confirm that `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate()` still succeeds?

Comment: @mklement0 No, `AppActivate()` exhibits the same behaviour as `SetForegroundWindow()` on my machine (both flash the taskbar button only), that's why I thought the former is implemented by calling the latter. That link is to a very old answer, so the hack has propably been prevented from working in newer Windows versions.

Comment: Thanks, @zett42. Does `$outVal = 0; (Add-Type -PassThru -Name WinApi -Namespace pg -MemberDefinition @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, ref UInt32 pvParam, uint fWinIni);
'@)::SystemParametersInfo(0x2000 <# SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT #>, 0, [ref] $outVal, 0); $outVal` return (`$true` and) a nonzero value for you?

Comment: Yes, `$true` and `20000`. It matches the value from the registry.

Comment: Thanks, the mystery is why on my machine it reports `0`, even though the registry also shows `20000`

Comment: I don't have an explanation for that. You may use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to determine which registry key(s) are actually queried by `SystemParametersInfo()`.

Comment: Thanks, @zett42: I tried (not too hard) and came up short, and ended up creating a question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/73735129/45375, which contains additional background info, including with respect to Windows 11.